# Control collapse/expand status upon rebuild of xxforms:tree

Tags: treeview, orbeon, xforms

I have a tree view based on xxforms:tree. On the form I edit properties that influence the status of that tree. After saving my properties, the tree gets rebuilt (not by my choosing, but apparently as part of default behavior) but without retaining the collapse/expand status of the items in that tree. In my case that leads to full expansion.

We use a dated version of Orbeon (v3.9) but I'm not seeing anything in newer version with regards to this. Is there any way to influence that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comment in [Tree.js](http://goo.gl/X4Q3Jx) which says "Expand nodes corresponding to values that were previously expanded". But if it doesn't work out of the box for you, it might be a bug, or it might not be designed to take place in certain kind of updates, who knows. There doesn't seem to be a specific way to keep nodes expanded.

I fear that `xxforms:tree` hasn't been maintained since 3.9 at all. So using a newer version wouldn't help.

For reference here is [the documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/selection-controls#TOC-Tree-appearance).